# YesQL/pgsql "could not determine data type of parameter $1"

Tags: postgresql, clojure, hugsql

I'm trying to use `NULL` to reuse queries for both specific searches as well as returning index (basically implementing the idea discussed here http://dev.solita.fi/2015/12/29/SQL-in-applications.html). However, I'm getting `ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1` anytime I try to use the function body with the `[]` params.

Here's the clojure

```
(defn get-ips
  "Get a list of IPs and their User Ids"
  ([] (ip-addresses {:uids nil}))
  ([uids] (ip-addresses {:uids uids})))
```

Here's the sql

```
-- name: ip-addresses
SELECT ipo.ip_address_id::varchar as address, ipo.user_id
FROM ip_ownerships AS ipo
WHERE :uids IS NULL OR ipo.user_id IN (:uids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just found the answer. The solution is to manually cast the parameter's type:

```
-- name: ip-addresses
SELECT ipo.ip_address_id::varchar as address, ipo.user_id
FROM ip_ownerships AS ipo
WHERE :uids::int IS NULL OR ipo.user_id IN (:uids)
```